# React Router With Axios Authentication

Tags: reactjs, authentication, axios

The goal is to prevent the user to access any pages if is is not Logged In.

The issue is that the route redirect to the Login page before I am able to call a request to ask for access using Axios.

I am using routes and doing a post request in order to get the token access.

If the parameter auth.isAutenticated is equal to true means that the user will be able to acess the page, otherwise show be redirect to /login.

I am using privateRoute, as follows:

```
let auth = {
  isAutenticated: false
}

axios.post('/auth/getUserInfo', { withCredentials: true })
      .then(res => {
        const dados = res.data
        **auth.isAutenticated = true**

      }).catch(err => {
        console.log('ERRO: ' + err)
      })

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (

  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    auth.isAutenticated === true
      ? <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect to='/Login' />

  )} />
)


class App extends React.Component {
  
  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Router>
          <PrivateRoute path='/' exact component={Home} />
          <Route path='/Login' component={Login} />
          <Route path='/Signup' component={Signup} />
          <Route path='/Confirmation' component={Confirmation} />
          <Route path='/Activation' component={Activation} />
          <Route path='/PasswordReset' component={PasswordReset} />
          <Route path='/EmailSent' component={EmailSent} />
          <Route path='/PasswordChange' component={PasswordChange} />
        </Router>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App
```

How do I wait for the http request in order to check if the user can stay on the page or must be redirect to the Login page?

I think the "issue" might be related to the asyncronous nature of the axios post request, because when I create a function to update de auth.isAutenticated directly, instead of getting from HTTP request, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Move the call of `axios.post` inside the component, in this case, should be in the`componentDidMount` method, if you were using hooks you should use `useEffect` (I strongly recommend you to check [this](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data/)).

Comment: I will read the documentation you suggested, thank you. But, could you please provide a code moving the call os axios.post to the component? I could not undertand how to do that.